# What kernel will be installed with 18.04.3 next week?

Tags: 18.04, kernel

I've checked both [Kernel Support](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Support#A18.04.x_Ubuntu_Kernel_Support) and [Kernel/LTS Enablement](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack) wiki pages but they are both quite outdated, still showing TBD even for events that have already happened.

[image]

If 18.04.3 point release is issued next week as [scheduled](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseSchedule), what kernel will it include for `linux-generic-hwe-18.04`?

Comment: You may get a clue from the items marked "Proposed" in https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/bionic-changes/2019-July/date.html. For example: https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/bionic-changes/2019-July/021405.html

Comment: @DKBose thanks for the tip about checking "proposed". That item you linked is quite verbose, but putting `linux-generic-hwe-18.04` into ubuntuupdates.org showed a proposed v 5.0 kernel.  https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package_metas?exact_match=1&q=linux-generic-hwe-18.04

Comment: My bad! You can search the first link for hwe and that too has, for example, "[ubuntu/bionic-proposed] linux-hwe 5.0.0-21.22~18.04.1 (Accepted)   Andy Whitcroft"

Comment: @DKBose if you'd like to post that as an answer, I'll be glad to accept it.

Comment: BTW, I'll be staying with 4.15… since I haven't switched to the HWE stack.

Comment: I had to do that with one old system as well, otherwise the Nvidia driver wouldn't compile.

Comment: No, please do so yourself. I really not familiar with the kernel terminology.